# CL: How can I traverse thru all physical files in a Library?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to create a CL that displays latest version names of all Physical Files in a library. Using library name as input parameter, how can I display the names of all Physical Files? Once I get the names, I can proceed with versions but I am stuck on this. Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Old school answer**

The Display Object Description (DSPOBJD) command has an output parm that accepts *OUTFILE.  You simply use the model file, QADSPOBJ, in your `DCLF` statment and use `OVRDBF` to override to your actual output file prior to using the `RCVF` command to read the first record.

Problems with that is that the format of the output file could change with a new version or even with the application of a PTF.

**Generic Modern answer**
Use ILE CL and the List Objects (QUSLOBJ) API.  The returned data is dumped into a user space.  You can use the user space APIs to access it inside your ILE CL program.

**Table (PF) specific modern answer**
(Taken from an answer by jmarkmurphy)
You can also try using SQL as referenced by John Y. Here is a Query that will return all the physical files in a library:

```
select * 
from qsys2.systables
where table_type in ('P', 'T')
  and table_schema = 'MYLIB'
  and file_type = 'D'
```

Comment: I am looking for list of Physical Files in the library, this is not giving me that info

Comment: @uSeruSher - They will give you what you need. What have you tried? If using DSPOBJD, don't forget you can use `*ALL` as the object name.

Comment: Personally, I am not a fan of the APIs, especially if you have to build the calls from scratch. (Different story if you already have wrappers lying around.) The "old school" way is simpler and shouldn't be discouraged. (It's scraping `*PRINT` output which should be discouraged.) Also, the *new* new way is using SQL and the DB2 for i catalogs and services.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using SQL as referenced by John Y. Here is a Query that will return all the physical files in a library:

```
select * 
from qsys2.systables
where table_type in ('P', 'T')
  and table_schema = 'MYLIB'
  and file_type = 'D'
```

Note that `table_type` includes 'T' which is an SQL table, and appears as a physical file in DSPOBJD. `file_type` differentiates between data and source files.

Comment: I added your info to my answer